# How to determine the id of a data in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm currently working on an ms access database in vb.net. 
And I need a code that can determine which data I am updating in the database. Because when I try to update the data, the previous data is being cloned and it will generate two data(the updated and the previous data), and the program will also generate a random id number for the updated data, which is not good.
Here is my code for the update button:
 'update
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

```
    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item(1) = TextBox13.Text
    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item(2) = TextBox14.Text
    ds.Tables("GH").Rows(INC).Item(3) = TextBox15.Text


    da.Update(ds, "GH")

    MsgBox("Data updated")
```

My code for form load:
 con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=F:\ACCESS DATABASE\search.mdb"
        con.Open()

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM GH"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "GH")
    con.Close()
```

I'm using system.data.oledb namespace

Here are my declarations:

```
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me at all, but if you want to find the last ID of an insert, you would usually check the results of "SELECT @@IDENTITY" immediately after the record is inserted.